# Shell Script to get date part from file and then compare it with last 2 days

Tags: bash, shell

I have a requirement where I need to extract the date part from a file name and then that date has to be compared with last 2 days and  the date in file should not be older than 2 days.

For example I have a list of file names coming in  a file like.

```
kuna_Project_10262017.txt
kuna_ProjectProfessional_10262017.txt
ffs_Programs_10_22_17_03_33.txt
```

I am extracting the date  for first two with

```
row=($(awk -F '[_.]' '{print $3}' FFS_FILES.txt))
```

`Row` is a array containing the date part.

I am trying to use for loops to compare it.
But  I am not able to compare the date after extraction with last 2 previous date as the format of input string is not the format it should expect, and also getting the date from the third file name is little strange.

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample script with comments.

```
CompareSec=$((60*60*24*2));   #number of seconds in two days
now=$(date "+%s" -d 'now');      #current time in seconds since EPOCH

while read file ; do
 TimeStampRaw=$(echo "${file}" \
 | sed 's/\([A-Z,a-z]*_[A-Z,a-z]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_\)\([0-9][0-9].*\)/\120\2/' \
 | sed 's/[A-Z,a-z_.]//g' \
 | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\3\1\2 \4/')

 # sed 's/\([A-Z,a-z]*_[A-Z,a-z]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_\)\([0-9][0-9].*\)/\120\2/' 
 # adds 20 before short format of year ( 17 -> 2017, 18 -> 2018 ) in files named ffs_Programs_10_22_17_03_33.txt

 # sed 's/[A-Z,a-z_.]//g'
 # delete any letters, dots and lines from text, leaving only numbers

 # sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{4\}\)\(.*\)/\3\1\2 \4/'
 # puts Year at first, then month, day and optionaly time in format YYYYmmdd HHMM

 TimeStampSec=$(date +%s -d "${TimeStampRaw}")
 #file time in senconds since EPOCH

 TimeStampHum=$(date -d "${TimeStampRaw}")
 #file time in Human format

 if [ $((${TimeStampSec} + ${CompareSec})) -ge ${now} ] ; then 
      echo "${file} is newer than ${CompareSec} Sec. (${TimeStampHum})"
 else
      echo "${file} is older than ${CompareSec} Sec. (${TimeStampHum})"
 fi

done <1.txt
```

Contents of 1.txt:

```
$ cat 1.txt 
kuna_Project_10262017.txt
kuna_ProjectProfessional_10262017.txt
ffs_Programs_10_22_17_03_33.txt
teSt_fiLe_05_07_18_03_33.txt
teSt_fiLe_05072018.txt
```

Output is:

```
kuna_Project_10262017.txt is older than 172800 Sec. (Thu Oct 26 00:00:00 MSK 2017)
kuna_ProjectProfessional_10262017.txt is older than 172800 Sec. (Thu Oct 26 00:00:00 MSK 2017)
ffs_Programs_10_22_17_03_33.txt is older than 172800 Sec. (Sun Oct 22 03:33:00 MSK 2017)
teSt_fiLe_05_07_18_03_33.txt is newer than 172800 Sec. (Mon May  7 03:33:00 MSK 2018)
teSt_fiLe_05072018.txt is newer than 172800 Sec. (Mon May  7 00:00:00 MSK 2018)
```

Comment: All sed commands may be in one sed script. This will do it faster. But I devided it in 3 lines for best unterstanding.

Comment: You can easily chain `sed a | sed b | sed c` into `sed -e a -e b -e c` with no loss of legibility. This isn't entirely portable but you can equivalently split the script on newlines (`sed 'a#b#c'` where each `#` represents a literal newline).